# guibas stolfi delaunay triangulation distorted output

Tags: gnuplot, triangulation, delaunay

I am using the delaunay triangulation code by Geoff Leach based on the guibas stolfi algorithm.

[here's the link](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/%7Egl/research/comp_geom/delaunay/delaunay.html)

I took randomly generated integers between 50 to 1550 as the coordinates for the points.When i take more than 280 points the output gets distorted.

[this is the distorted output](http://tinypic.com/r/210lpbq/5)

Comment: could you explain the output?  The site says that the output is a file with one point per line and that the output is the "edges" but, you need 2 points for an edge, so I'm a little confused how it is structured...

Comment: well i did it.it was easy.just had to leave a blank line for gnuplot to break line continuation

Comment: @mgilson the input is 1 point per line,the output are two points forming an edge.Anyways thanx for such quick response.

Comment: I suspected that you just needed to add blank lines in the appropriate places.  I'm glad you figured it out.  You should probably post an answer and accept it just so this question isn't sitting around forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, isolved the distorted output thing.
It was due to the incorrect scaling.My random points were in a square of side of 1500,had to change it to a rectangle corresponding to my aspect ratio.Gnuplot preserves the aspect ratio.
Everything's fine now